# Searching for value within 2d Array then returning true or false

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, parameters

I have this an array filled with random numbers.  The user enters a number and then my program is supposed to find it within the array and display what row and column index it was found on.  It is the `SearchArray()` Method that does the searching.  My program currently will ask for a number then If i input anything between 15 and 96 it crashes Please help!

The SearchArray() method will return a bool to indicate if the number searched for was found or not. Its parameter is supposed to have: An integer that is the number to be searched for, a two-dimensional array to search, an out reference integer parameter that will represent the row index and an out reference integer parameter that will represent the column index This method will use the first parameter and the two-dimensional array and will search the array for the number chosen by the GetNumber() method. I must Initialize the row and column parameters to -1. As the program goes through the array, if the number is found, assign the row and column parameters to the row and column index numbers where it is found and stop searching the array right away. The method is supposed to return a Boolean value to indicate whether or not the number was found.

When It crashes it tells me this : Index was outside the boundary of array

Here is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[,] initialArray = new int[3, 5];

        FillArray(initialArray);
        PrintArray(initialArray);
        SumRows(initialArray);
        SumCols(initialArray);
        SumArray(initialArray);
        int rows;
        int cols;

        int userInput = GetNumber();

        if (SearchArray(userInput, initialArray, out rows, out cols))
        {
        Console.WriteLine("your number, " + userInput + " was found at row index " + rows + " and column index " + cols);
        }

        else
        {
        Console.WriteLine("Number not found");
        }
    }

    public static void FillArray(int[,] arrayOfRandoms)
    {
        Random num = new Random();
        for (int r = 0; r < arrayOfRandoms.GetLength(0); r++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < arrayOfRandoms.GetLength(1); c++)
            {
                arrayOfRandoms[r, c] = num.Next(15, 97);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void PrintArray(int[,] arrayPrints)
    {
        for (int r = 0; r < arrayPrints.GetLength(0); r++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < arrayPrints.GetLength(1); c++)
            {
                Console.Write("{0,3:F0}", arrayPrints[r, c]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("");
    }

    public static void SumRows(int[,] rowsArray)
    {
        int sumOfRows;
        for (int r = 0; r < rowsArray.GetLength(0); r++)
        {
            sumOfRows = 0;
            for (int c = 0; c < rowsArray.GetLength(1); c++)
            {
                sumOfRows += rowsArray[r, c];
            }
            Console.WriteLine("The total sum for row "+ (r + 1) + " is:  " + sumOfRows + ".");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("");
    }

    public static void SumCols(int[,] columnArray)
    {
        int columnSum;
        for (int c = 0; c < columnArray.GetLength(1); c++)
        {
            columnSum = 0;
            for (int r = 0; r < columnArray.GetLength(0); r++)
            {
                columnSum += columnArray[r, c];
            }
            Console.WriteLine("The total sum for column " + (c + 1) + " is:  " + columnSum + ".");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("");
    }

    public static void SumArray(int[,] arraySum)
    {
        int sumOfArray = 0;
        for (int r = 0; r < arraySum.GetLength(0); r++)
        {

            for (int c = 0; c < arraySum.GetLength(1); c++)
            {
                sumOfArray += arraySum[r, c];
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Total for sum of the Array is:  "  + sumOfArray + "\n");
    }

    public static int GetNumber()
    {
        Console.Write("Please enter a number between 15 and 96:  ");
        int userNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        while (userNumber > 96 || userNumber < 15)
        {
            Console.Write("Number not between 15 and 96.  Try again:  ");
            userNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        return userNumber;
    }


    public static bool SearchArray(int searchedNum, int [,] rArray, out int indexOfRow, out int indexOfColumn)
    {
        indexOfRow = -1;
        indexOfColumn = -1;


        for (int c = 0; c < rArray.GetLength(0); c++)
        {  
        for (int r = 0; r < rArray.GetLength(1); r++)
            {
                indexOfRow = r;
                indexOfColumn = c;

                if (rArray[r, c].Equals(searchedNum))
                {
                    return true;
                }

            }

        }
        return false;

    }

}
```

Comment: Where does it crash, what is the full error you get? What is your expected output? Update your question with answers to the above.

Comment: What exception are you getting? More detail on how it crashes please.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Comment: I updated the question It should be alot more detailed now any more specificity that is needed I will supply. please help.

Comment: The exception is called IndexOutOfRange Exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `SearchArray`, your code

```
for (int c = 0; c < rArray.GetLength(0); c++)
{  
    for (int r = 0; r < rArray.GetLength(1); r++)
    {
        indexOfRow = r;
        indexOfColumn = c;

        if (rArray[r, c].Equals(searchedNum))
```

is wrong - in specific you probably switched around the rows and columns at

```
for (int c = 0; c < rArray.GetLength(0); c++)
{  
    for (int r = 0; r < rArray.GetLength(1); r++)
    {
```

You can fix it by switching the variable names in `for (int c = 0 ...` and `for (int r = 0 ...`. As of now, when trying to access Row 3 and Column 5, for example, your program is actually accessing Row 5 and Column 3, leading to an IndexOutOfRange exception.